# Detect a change of any text area in the page and add the changed data in this specific input into other table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have this web form, that is enumerating human teeth with their scientific number:

[image]

Usually, a Doctor add changes to a tooth that was working on. Lets take er example, the number 18 tooth, where it is crownded. But he did another action to it, in a later appointment, so he go and add those changes:

[image]

What I want is, to detect what text areas are changed, and what didn't changed, because the teeth table contain 32 column and each column represent a tooth, and I need to detect which data are changed so I can perform another `insert` query into another table.

My question is how to detect a change of any column of 32, and to use it to insert the new data into another 2 column table.

Here is an HTML code of some of the text areas:

```
  <textarea style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="one" name="one" placeholder="18 - 3rd Molar"><?php echo $resTeeth['one'] ?></textarea>
                    <textarea style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="two" name="two" placeholder="17 - 2nd Molar"><?php echo $resTeeth['two'] ?></textarea>
                    <textarea style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="three" name="three" placeholder="16 - 1st Molar"><?php echo $resTeeth['three'] ?></textarea>
                    <textarea style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="four" name="four" placeholder="15 - 2nd Bicuspid"><?php echo $resTeeth['four'] ?></textarea>
                    <textarea style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="five" name="five" placeholder="14 - 1st Bicuspid"><?php echo $resTeeth['five'] ?></textarea>
                    <textarea style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="six" name="six" placeholder="13 - cuspid"><?php echo $resTeeth['six'] ?></textarea>
                    <textarea style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="seven" name="seven" placeholder="12 - lateral"><?php echo $resTeeth['seven'] ?></textarea>
                    <textarea style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="eight" name="eight" placeholder="11 - central"><?php echo $resTeeth['eight'] ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? I would use `data-value` for such requirement..

Comment: jQuery usage ok with you?

Comment: Yeah of course. If 2 text area are changed, I need to get the value of those 2, concat with each other and add them into a table with a specific date. Any language or library is welcomed

Comment: May be `$('textarea').each(function(index,elem){ if($(elem).val() != $(elem).data('value')){ alert('Changed'); } })` if `jQ` is fine with you..

Comment: I can't just figure it how, to make a jsfiddle, I was thinking about a solution since 2 days and still can't even know how

Comment: A complete answer to this question may be a lot of code, and, there are so many ways you can accomplish this. Can you perhaps narrow down exactly what it is you need? is it just the JavaScript detection of `textarea` edits?

Comment: Look, if a text area contains any previous action like per example `crown`, and the doctor later on added a new action, so the new value is `crown - extdo`, what I need to get is the `extdo` and process it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/73pmxs7a/2/

Comment: @RayonDabre that is exactly what I want but what if 2 or more text area are changed ?

Comment: This is just a demo.. You can have a `loop/.each` which will test things on button click..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/73pmxs7a/3/

Comment: That is it. Thanks @RayonDabre add in an answer to check it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attribute to store extra information related with `HTML element`.

Keep value in `data-value` attribute and test it with `value` property of the element.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var changed = [];
  var unChanged = [];
  $('textarea').each(function() {
    if ($(this).data('value') != this.value) {
      changed.push(this.id);
    } else {
      unChanged.push(this.id);
    }
  });
  $('#data').html((changed.join(', ') || 'None') + ' are changed!<br>' + (unChanged.join(', ') || 'None') + ' are not changed!');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data"></div>
<button>Test</button>
<br>
<textarea data-value="one" style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="one" name="one" placeholder="18 - 3rd Molar">one</textarea>
<textarea data-value="two" style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="two" name="two" placeholder="17 - 2nd Molar">two</textarea>
<textarea data-value="three" style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="three" name="three" placeholder="16 - 1st Molar">three</textarea>
<textarea data-value="four" style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="four" name="four" placeholder="15 - 2nd Bicuspid">four</textarea>
<textarea data-value="five" style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="five" name="five" placeholder="14 - 1st Bicuspid">five</textarea>
<textarea data-value="six" style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="six" name="six" placeholder="13 - cuspid">six</textarea>
<textarea data-value="seven" style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="seven" name="seven" placeholder="12 - lateral">seven</textarea>
<textarea data-value="eight" style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="eight" name="eight" placeholder="11 - central">eight</textarea>
```

### [Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/73pmxs7a/5/)

To read `live-change` of every `textarea` element, use `input` event.

```js
$('textarea').on('input', function() {
  if ($(this).data('value') != this.value) {
    $('#data').text(this.id + ' is changed!');
  } else {
    $('#data').text(this.id + ' is not changed!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data"></div>
<textarea data-value="one" style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="one" name="one" placeholder="18 - 3rd Molar">one</textarea>
<textarea data-value="two" style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="two" name="two" placeholder="17 - 2nd Molar">two</textarea>
<textarea data-value="three" style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="three" name="three" placeholder="16 - 1st Molar">three</textarea>
<textarea data-value="four" style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="four" name="four" placeholder="15 - 2nd Bicuspid">four</textarea>
<textarea data-value="five" style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="five" name="five" placeholder="14 - 1st Bicuspid">five</textarea>
<textarea data-value="six" style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="six" name="six" placeholder="13 - cuspid">six</textarea>
<textarea data-value="seven" style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="seven" name="seven" placeholder="12 - lateral">seven</textarea>
<textarea data-value="eight" style="height:50px" class="form-control" id="eight" name="eight" placeholder="11 - central">eight</textarea>
```

### [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/73pmxs7a/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the usage of jQuery is ok with you, it's pretty straightforward. Let's assume you have a textarea like this:

```
<textarea data-tooth="12">12 - </textarea>
<textarea data-tooth="13">13 - </textarea>
```

Then the script could look like this:

```
$('textarea').on('change', textareaChange);

function textareaChange(){
  var toothNumber = $(this).data('tooth');
  var value = $(this).text().replace(tooth+' - ');
  alert(toothNumber+': '+value); // would result in "18: crown, change#2
}
```

Then you can process the data however you want to.

Comment: even if multiple text boxes are changed ? Per example if a text area contain `crown` and the doctor added `crown - extdo`, what I need is to get only the `extdo` and process it

Comment: You could store the original value in an html data attribute, and then compare `$(this).attr('data-original-value')` with `$(this).val()`

Comment: Didn't understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

"I was thinking about a solution since 2 days and still can't even know how" - sounds like it might be time to try approaching the problem differently?

How about this: remove the editable text areas. Instead, have a static "work done" div, with an input box for "new work done". When new work is submitted, it is appended to the "work done" div, and sent to the server to update the database. If the page is refreshed, the "work done" div has all of the work in it because the server was updated.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/602k1L3a/

## JavaScript

```
$(".tooth .new-work-button").click(function() {
  var tooth = $(this).parent();
  var newWork = tooth.find(".new-work-done").val();
  tooth.find(".work-done").append(" - " + newWork);
  alert("Update server with '" + newWork + "' for " + tooth.attr('id'));
})
```

## HTML

```
<div class="tooth" id="tooth-4">
  <div class="work-done">crown</div>
  <input class="new-work-done" type="text"/>
  <input class="new-work-button" type="button" value="Record New Work"/>
</div>
```

## Back-End

Have an api endpoint that accepts POST requests with a tooth id and new work done, and append the work done to the tooth.

If you need to undo work also, it may be time to add an extra table to your database for tooth_work which has a string column for work and a foreign key to the tooth id.

Then when you render your html you would select all work for a given tooth and combine the strings with " - ".

Comment: Okay, waiting for it

Comment: Thanks a lot. The link is really helpful